# FullScreen Loading View didn't work

Tags: objective-c, ios

I have been working on a fullscreen loading view for my apps, but it can't block any user interaction. The way I implement it is like this:

1. Create a singleton object - `LoadingView`
2. Call `[LoadingView show]` - add the loading view to `[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] window]`

So I want to ask :

1. Is my concept wrong?
2. Are there any method calls that can disable all user interaction to my apps?
3. Is there another better way to do this? (I prefer knowing about the principle inside than just using others' libraries)

Thanks

Comment: You can add the view of your LoadingView controller as a subview of your current view controller. And then set the property self.view.window.userInteractionEnabled = NO;

Answer (score 1):

I use such way to block user interaction:

1. create UIView with window frame
2. set view's user interaction enabled to true
3. (optional) add UIActivityIndicator to view
4. add view to window subviews
5. when I need to show it I set hidden to NO and use bringSubviewToFront function to show loading view
6. when I don't need it I set hidden to YES and use sendSubviewToBack

---

```
id application = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
UIView *loadingView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:[[application window] frame]];
loadingView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
loadingView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:0 alpha:0.5];
[[application window] addSubview:loadingView];
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you wanting to create a splash screen when the application starts? If so, all you need to do is add an image file called `Default.png` and/or `Default@2x.png` (for retina displays) to your project. This image will work as a splash screen for when the app launches.

You can also control the splash screen `info.plist` file.

Read more about the iOS launch screen [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/App-RelatedResources/App-RelatedResources.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH6-SW12).